# Solution to first order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I argue that the following IVP has no meaningful solution?

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{(x^2-t)},x(1)=0$$

The basic condition for existence of solution is that $\sqrt{(x^2-t)}$ is differentiable and $$\frac{\partial{\sqrt{(x^2-t)}}}{\partial{t}},\frac{\partial{\sqrt{(x^2-t)}}}{\partial{x}}$$ are bounded.

Should I actually check differentiability? or can it be argued, somehow without actually computing the limit of quotient ration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is defined only in he region where the expression inside the square root is non-negative, that is
$$
D=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2:t\le x^2\}.
$$
The point $(0,1)$, which is the point giving the initial condition, is outside $D$. If there existed a solution it should satisfy
$$
y'(1)=\sqrt{x(1)^2-1}=\sqrt{-1},
$$
which is meaningless.

Comment: I don't agree with your explanation. Because the world has complex number. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%3D%28x%5E2-t%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2Cx%281%29%3D0.

Comment: @doraemonpaul It was clear to me, although I could be wrong, that the OP was asking about real solutions.